# git annex - how to verify 2 repositories are exactly identical

Tags: git-annex

How can I ensure that when I clone, sync, and get content from another git annex repository that I have setup an identical mirror?

I have used a tool like unison in the past which did a file to file comparison, but that is time and memory intensive.

Are there any other alternatives so I can perform a sanity check?  The main motivation for this is that I just made a clone of an existing repository it is smaller.  I expect it to be smaller because the old repository has unused or unreferenced objects, but it is quite a bit different in size.

So, I'd like to have some check I can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified git annex works as expected by doing the following:

1. get a sorted, unique file listing including .git contents (this ensures we have all of the git annex contents)
2. get a sorted, unique link listing including .git contents (this ensures we have the same repository structure)
3. compare file listings, ignore annex/transfer directory, git objects may be different, git annex contents should be identical
4. compare link listings, should be identical
5. run a git annex fsck or compare the checksum for all files (this is a file system issue)

This works, but can be a bit labor / time intensive.  Additionally, the process can be complicated further by having mirrors that are only partial copies.  For those mirrors, you need to only compare the content that you are expecting to have.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a built in sanity check (`git fsck`) that would point out generic problems with the git metadata structure. There is also a garbage collector (`git gc`) that would remove dangling and other superfluous stuff.

As for data integrity... basically this is a guarantee provided by git, the data you put in is the data you get out. If the `git log` (or even just the hash of the last commit) is identical then so is the data. Every step in git is checksummed, against the data, metadata, and previous; it's kind of like a blockchain, if the data changed anywhere so the checksums would too. If the checksums didn't match, git would complain a lot on checkout.

There's an old (2007-2008?) talk of Linus Torvalds about git you can watch on Youtube where IIRC he also speaks about the data integrity side of things. There is also some documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

In practice, people just don't worry about this since git magically takes care of it. You just do 'git status' to see if you have to pull/push/commit changes to keep up with the origin.

Additional space usage can also have other reasons... `git stash` can be a space hog if you ever used it.

This is also where you have differences in cloned repositories: git does not care about the local stuff that never got commited. If it's not commited it does not exist as far as the clones are concerned.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow completely missed the "annex" part in your question ;) let me know if this answer is nonsense when it comes to annex, and I'll remove it.

Comment: I trust the answer for git and for the several years I've used it, I'm confident it works.  That is a fairly detailed answer so I'll accept it for git.  But ... for git annex, the actual files aren't stored in git, so I was thinking the actual validation is a bit harder.  I'm looking for a quicker and easier solution to using unison.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking only of regular git, sorry... https://git-annex.branchable.com/scalability/ does mention that files are checksummed but I don't know which command would fire a re-verification of those checksums. (and checksumming large files is slow too)

Comment: Right, short of check-summing the files which I could do, unison may be the best bet, but I was really looking for what other people do / what is the recommended practice.  I was thinking that something quick to do as a sanity check is to list all of the files (links), sort them, and then compare the list of files and make sure both repositories have the same version.  That would be quick and would let you know right away if something is awry.